# How can I get the Really Value of the Windows Registry Keys by C# with .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I'm trying to read a value of Windows Registry Key using C# with .Net Framework, the real value of the key is `%SystemRoot%`, but the value I've got is `C:\Windows`. How Can I get the string `%SystemRoot%` instead of the string `C:\Windows`?

Here's the code I used to read the value of the key:

```
RegistryKey rkCurrentUser = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Environment");

foreach (string name in rkCurrentUser.GetValueNames())
{
    Console.WriteLine("The type of the {0} is {1}:", rkCurrentUser.GetValue(name), rkCurrentUser.GetValueKind(name));
}
```

Comment: Wut? I dont get it... so do you want to get back the string `"%SystemRoot%"`?? Why dont you simply use it directly?

Comment: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() seems a more robust way to do this?

Comment: Because I need to write back the original value into the windows registry key. @Josué Cortina

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well your question, you need just to change your code to this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The type of the {0} is {1}:", rkCurrentUser.GetValue(name,"",RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames), rkCurrentUser.GetValueKind(name));
```

Check official documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvalueoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2